# ERROR: Unable to query GPU information

Tags: linux, kali-linux, nvidia, gpu

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Проблема с запуском kali linux, я нашёл статью где это проблема  [решается](https://codeby.net/threads/ustranenie-problem-s-kali-linux-msi-tred.62537/) но вылезла другая ошибка `ERROR: Unable to query GPU information`  я так понял то что не включен графический процессор. Как эту ошибку исправить подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: А Вам точно нужен именно Kali Linux? он не очень дружелюбен к новичкам.

Comment: Да именно он ибо, я на нем работаю а с такой проблемой сталкиваюсь в первые гуглил ничего не нашел.

Comment: это дистрибутив для тех, кто ищет уязвимости и тех, кто работает в безопасности. Обычно для них это не проблема.

Comment: @KoVadim я не давно начал работать в сфере ИБ и повторюсь я столкнулся с этой проблемой в первые.

Comment: у меня эта же строка возвращает ровно такую же ошибку. Но при этом nvidia работает как нужно

Comment: @KoVadim хм странно, а у меня вообще не запускается kali

Comment: потому что у меня генту:)